# Overloading ostream << operator returning address

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

I am making a simple *Person* class which derives from Object.
Each person has a name (char*).
I would like to be able to print the name of the person using cout.
I am not achieving the results desired.
Here is my code:

Person.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#ifndef _PERSON_H_
#define _PERSON_H_
using namespace std;

class Object {};

class Person : public Object {
private:
    char* m_name;


public:
    Person(char* input);
    ~Person();
    char* getName() const;
    //Set to friend because otherwise I was getting a compilation error.
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person& p);
};



#endif // _PERSON_H_
```

Person.cc

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

Person::Person(char* input) {
    m_name = new char[strlen(input)];
    strncpy(m_name, input, strlen(input));
}

char* Person::getName() const{
    return m_name;
}

/*Person& Person::operator=(const Person &rhs) {
    delete [] m_name;
    m_name = new char[strlen(rhs.getName())];
    strncpy(m_name, rhs.getName(), strlen(rhs.getName()));
    return *this;
}*/

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person& p) {
    os << p.getName();
    return os;
}

Person::~Person() {}

int main() {
    char* tmp = "dave";
    Person * p = new Person(tmp);
    cout<<p;
}
```

Output with the code above:

```
0x7fbba3c04b60
```

If I change the last line of the main to:

```
cout<<*p
```

I get the desired result, which is *dave*.

My references:
[Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx)

How do I get `cout<<p` to print `dave`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want your object to work in both cases

```
cout << p ;
cout << *p;
```

you have to overload your operator for pointers also,  so you can add this to your code and keep the old one:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person* p);

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person* p) {
    os << p->m_name << "\n";
    return os;
}
```

so you have two overloaded operator functions

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person* p)
```

and

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person p)
```

Comment: That is what I did. Although someone above mentioned that it isn't a good idea.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't see your comment. I think it is a solution to the problem but it's not the best idea , but usually if you pass your pointer as const so you can insure that your pointer is initialized

Answer (score 2):

`std::ostream& operator<<` has an overload for pointers that prints the address in hexadecimal format (unless they are pointers to character types, in which case it assumes a null-terminated string.) You invoke that overload when you say

```
cout<<p;
```

because `p` is a pointer. You can test this with other pointers:

```
int i = 0;
int* pi = &i;
double d = 3.14;
double* pd = &d;

cout << pi << ", " << pd << '\n';
```

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it by changing the arguments that the overload function receives to pointer: `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person * p);`

Comment: @Airwavezx You really shouldn't do that. You should let pointers be printed out as pointers.

Comment: I edited the line, it was supposed to be `*p` not just `p`. Is that okay?

Comment: No, You really shouldn't do that. You should let pointers be printed out as pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* overload `operator <<` for `Person*`, but doing so would be extremely unidiomatic and confusing to every other user of C++.

The right thing to do in C++ is to not pretend that a pointer to an object is the object.

Answer (score 0):

You are achieving exactly the result you want. Simply using

`cout << p`

calls the overload `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, void*)` which displays the address the pointer `p` points to.

`cout << *p`

dereferences the pointer and calls your overload.

Answer (score 0):

You COULD provide an operator that takes `Person* p` as well. But the typical implementation is to just place a star in front of the pointer - the compiler will then simply pass the pointer anyway, since the call is using a reference.